# Any way to convert C# XML Comments into C# Comment?

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0

**Update:**
ILSPY, DotPeek and JustDecompile automatically support what I am looking.

I just want to convert my C# XML Comments into Comments.

**Input**

```xml
<member name="P:...">
      <summary>.......</summary>
      <returns>
        ......
      </returns>
</member>
```

**Output**,

```
/// <summary>
/// ...
/// </summary>
/// <returns>...</returns>
```

Comment: And what's the problem ?

Comment: I have a big C# comment xml file. I need to convert this into C# comments. Doing this manually is pain for me, @JaroslawWaliszko

Comment: Okay... And what problem are you having with your approach?

Comment: @BobHorn, Currently I am creating some extensions method of an existing assembly. I have the xml file of this assembly. So, I need to use the same C# special comments (which have been used in the assembly) in my extension method

Comment: @user960567 [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without more context for what your ultimately trying to get out of it, this should convert Xml into comments.  Nothing real tricky going on here...

```
string content =
@"<member name=""P:..."">
  <summary>This is the summary.</summary>
  <returns>This is the return info.</returns>
  </member>";

XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(content);                        
foreach (var member in doc.Descendants("member"))
{
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

     sb.AppendLine("/// <summary>");
     sb.AppendLine("/// " + member.Descendants("summary").Select(e => e.Value).FirstOrDefault());
     sb.AppendLine("/// </summary>");

     sb.AppendLine("/// <returns>");
     sb.AppendLine("/// " + member.Descendants("returns").Select(e => e.Value).FirstOrDefault());
     sb.AppendLine("/// </returns>");

     // sb.ToString() contains the comments for this member
 }
```

You'll probably need to do more to get it exactly how you want.

Comment: There are lot of other thing in the xml comment file beside summary and returns

Comment: I agree, but you haven't really said anything more or included those in your input/output.  A more precise question will get you a more precise answer.

Comment: This is the problem with trying to answer this type of general question. Nice work.

Comment: I need to convert everything in the assembly.xml into C# comments.

Comment: @user960567 The problem is that you're giving us requirements and expecting us to do the job for you. You need to show your effort in completing this problem, then ask questions about where you're specifically stuck. If you want me to do this for you, we can talk about my fees for doing so.

Comment: Patrick I have mark your post as answer. Please update your answer to point a Disassembler. From my checking, ILSPY, DotPeek and JustDecompile automatically support this what I am looking. @BobHorn Thanks anyway. But b+