# How to Import documentation from .xml file to .cs file programmatically?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, documentation

I heve documentation in .xml file that looked like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<doc>
    <assembly>
        <name>ClassLibrary2</name>
    </assembly>
    <members>
        <member name="T:ClassLibrary2.Class1">
            <summary>
            Class1 Dummy documentation
            </summary>
        </member>
        <member name="M:ClassLibrary2.Class1.Func1">
            <summary>
            Func1 Dummy documentation
            </summary>
        </member>
    </members>
</doc>
```

And I wont to import the documentation to .cs file that looked like this:

```cs
namespace ClassLibrary2
{
    public class Class1
    {
        void Func1()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

So that after my import my file will look like this:

```cs
namespace ClassLibrary2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Class1 Dummy documentation
    /// </summary>
    public class Class1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Func1 Dummy documentation
        /// </summary>
        void Func1()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

How can I do this programmatically?

Should I use `CodeDOM` Or Visual Studio? Or `Roslyn` Or another tool?

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Interesting... Was it just stripped out of the .cs file in the past? I've only seen the XML generated from the .cs files themselves.

Comment: This question may lead to a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @BrootsWaymb Indeed, the documentation was taken from .CS files but it was accidentally deleted, and remains in the XML file and now needs to be returned. This is a very large amount of documentation.

Comment: Normally the xml docu is created from .cs file. Do you have also the dll or only the xml file?  If you have the dll you could use a deompiler to get the code. For example ILSPY

Comment: I'm surprised this question hasn't been asked a hundred times. One other example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13333211/any-way-to-convert-c-sharp-xml-comments-into-c-sharp-comment Use case: A company has private software, exports comments to XML, publishes docs via SandCastle. People without access to the source want to help fix to the docs. To avoid a two-step process with copy/paste into code source, it would be much better to regenerate in-line code comments from XML. The one Answer on this thread is incomplete. It would be nice to find/create an actual solution.

Answer (score 0):

use CodeDom, Roslyn is the compiler platform and will not help you for your problem.

1. Load the cs into a codedom graph
2. Find the methods / properties in the graph and add a CodeCommentStatement - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/how-to-create-an-xml-documentation-file-using-codedom
3. Generate a new source file from the graph (example is in the link I've provided )

EDIT:
maybe it's easier to use the Microsoft.CodeAnalysis (add the Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp nuget package) library of roslyn

```
var syntaxTree= CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(code);

//search for the methods and properties and add comments
// ** your code **
//

//getting the  new sourcecode
var root = (CompilationUnitSyntax)syntaxTree.GetRoot();
var mc= new ModelCollector();
mc.Visit(root);

string newCode = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mc.models);
```

Here is the Method for creating new comments:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.csharp.syntaxfactory.comment?view=roslyn-dotnet

complete doc of the lib:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.csharp?view=roslyn-dotnet

Comment: Is your solution also suitable for a project consisting of hundreds of CS files? Is CodeDom able to read many different files belonging to the same project?

Comment: shouldn't be a problem. haven't used the CodeDOM for such problem, only for creating autogenerated code . had no problems with the amount of classes or files. just load the xml documention file and then load the associated cs file into a codedom graph, add the comments and save the new one (for testing better into a new directory :D). then do this for the next xml documentation.

Comment: Can you provide an example of how to load a lot of .cs files to Codedom graph, thank you very much.

Comment: check  my edit, with Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp i think it will be easier to add the comments and getting a new code file